Wifi stopped working on Raspberry Pi 5 with Gentoo
I left my Raspberry Pi 5 running Gentoo Linux running for a few days and only now noticed that the wifi stopped working at some point. I have no idea why that could be, since I didn't change the system since the last time I accessed it through ssh. All I can say is that ip link says wlan0 is down, if I try to set it up I get no error message but when I check it is still shown as down, I can't connect through Network Manager but iw dev wlan0 info shows nothing unusual. Also, I sometimes get the message
brcmfmac: brcm_cfg00211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled

Any ideas?
Edit: I disabled the powersave using
$ sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off

but still can't access the network.

"iw dev wlan0 info shows nothing unusual" what DOES it show?
